# ASP.net Controller 404's for certain HTTP verbs

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am writing an ASP.net web API controller. I have an endpoint where I only support POSTs. I am writing error handling code to return HTTP 405 (rather than the default 404) for unsupported HTTP methods.

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("foobar")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post() 
{
    return NoContent();
}
```

For the remaining verbs, I have an error handling method:

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPatch]
[HttpDelete]
[HttpPut]
[ODataRoute("foobar")]
public async Task<IActionResult> NotSupported()
{
    // return http 405;
}
```

I have been making calls in Postman to test the functionality of this endpoint. With GET, the endpoint returns 201 as expected. However, only some of the other HTTP verbs are returning their expected responses. These calls are all being made with the exact same URLs, so I am baffled as to why only some verbs are reaching my `NotSupported` method.

- GET: 404
- PUT: 405
- PATCH: 405
- DELETE: 404

Comment: Are you targeting .net core?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is OData breaks your routing, it would be working without it. But you don't need to create a special controller action. Try this code, it was tested in Visual Studio

```
[ODataRoute("foobar")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post() 
{
     if( HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post.Method) return NoContent();

     return StatusCode(405);
}
```